# VS 2022: No me sale la opción de ASP.NET Core Web App (Model-View-Controller)

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Estoy empezando con un curso de .net core. Y en el tutorial al crear un nuevo proyecto se indica que seleccione la plantilla de ASP.NET Core Web App (Model-View-Controller) pero no me aparece, al escribir mvc sólo sale esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en el del tutorial se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Qué puedo palomear en el instalador en componentes individuales para tener esa plantilla o cuál sería?

Actualmente tengo estas opciones instaladas actualmente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También, cada que abro VS aparece el mensaje:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

probé instalarlo en una máquina virtual en Windows 10 y si me funciona y no aparece ese mensaje, qué puedo hacer para detectar la diferencia en mi máquina? tengo Windows 11

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar una captura de las opciones que tienes seleccionadas en el instalador de Visual Studio?

Comment: Hoola, intente crear el proyecto por consola con el siguiente comando:
dotnet new mvc --language "C#" Aquí se encuentra más información -> https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new

Comment: Ejecuté el comando pero al abrir el archivo me sale un error: `El tipo de resolucion del SDK “DotNetMSBuildSdkResolver" no se pudo cargar. Se produjo una excepcion en el inicializador de tipo de 'Microsoft.DotNet.DotNetSdkResolver.VSSettings'. G:\Proyectos\Core\Core.csproj` y el espacio de trabajo está vacío

Comment: Se añadieron las capturas de los componentes instalados

Comment: Intenta reparar la instalación ejecutando el instalador de Visual Studio como administrador.

Comment: Lo he hecho varias veces pero sigue igual, no sé que tenga mi máquina que se instala chueco, cada que abro el VS sale: "El paquete Visual Studio Common IDE Package* no se cargo correctamente.

El problema puede deberse a un cambio en la configuracion o a la instalacion de otra extension. Para obtener mas informacion, examine el archivo

'C:\Users\angel\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_befb8

ac2\ActivityLog.xml\

Reinidar Visual Studio podria ayudar a resolver el problema.
,¿Desea seguir mostrando este mensaje de error?" Te ha pasado alguna vez?

Comment: Lo instalé exitosamente en una máquina virtual, entonces concluí que mi windows11 estaba roto y formateé.